# Android app with payment in webview SECURITY QUESTION

Tags: android, security, browser, webview, payment

Working on android app. Besides multiple options it has, one of the possibilities is to do the payment. Since this is already implemented on web, I plan to just load the url in webview, login user and let him proceed with payment here.
What I want to know: is this approach safe?

For example let's take a look at 2 scenarios:

1. User enters web browser on his phone and does the payment via credit card.
2. user enters native app that opens webview and does the payment in native app (which loads same url from previous example in webview)

Are there any bigger security differences between these 2 approaches? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two use cases described in question are almost identical security-wise(at least there is no official info that says otherwise). It is because the webview of the Android OS basically [is a Chromium-based browser](https://www.chromium.org/developers/androidwebview/), which uses a lot of the same code as Chrome.

Moreover, most of the payment providers as Braintree or Stripe, have their mobile app embeddable UI and functionality provided as fully or partially web view-based components because it is more secure than the native(android or ios) approaches.

If you are still paranoid and want to use an actual Chrome browser instead of an Android web view disregarding previous info but want it to look like it is a part of your app flow, you can also do it. Chrome has a relatively new feature called [Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/) - [it is not that complicated to integrate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/guide-get-started/), basically the same as an ordinary web view. It won't give you as immense control over it as a web view provides but for simple displaying, it should be a preferable approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have questionmark above my head regarding one part. If security is same as in webview, why would payment providers like Braintree who allow normal payments on web browsers like chrome integrate mobile app embeddable UI's to improve security on natives (in situations where we use webview). Isn't this proof that webview is not as safe as web browser?

Comment: @Kratos nope. I was developing a thing using Braintree native elements(and APIs) and in order to use it in a certified way(yeah, you have to have a certificate for some of the domains you are about to use your merchant abilities) I had to have a lot of hustling around with cryptography, tls and other stuff in order to just mimic what already was working withing webview approach. Moreover, a lot of Braintree stuff that looks like native is actually a webview - all the 3ds stuff, pre-post verification and others. I am not that sure about other providers - but I assume it is pretty much the same.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. There goes my bounty haha. Anyways would like to add that I think I found 1 possible vulnerability in webview. It is situation when we enable javascript and in this case, we can be target of Cross Site Scripting if we don't take care well about security settings. But this is specific case I guess.

Comment: @Kratos, there are many vulnerabilities with both cases - if someone would really want to break it - nothing would stop them. And with the JS enabling - it is a developer mistake - so yeah with the webview - it is better to disable it(if you don't need it), though with Custom Tabs, you have no possibility to enable JS whatsoever, so it is kinda safer developer-wise. It doesn't stop hackers from decompiling your app though, enabling JS and injecting whatever and compiling it once more - so yeah.)) There are no completely safe ways, there are only safe enough...

Comment: Sure I agree on that one every programming related system is breakable. We can only make it harder for the attacker to break it and make him invest too much time so that it is not profitable for him to do so and make him give up.
Ok good talk all in all, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been down this path. I used WebView to start with, and didn't find it to be any more or less secure than Chrome, as it is based on Chromium. I cannot find and am not aware of any security issues with WebView that are not also an issue in Chrome. What forced me to switch from WebView to Chrome was, a Chrome users stored passwords for payment providers is not available in WebView. This is a significant inconvenience for the end-user.